# VSCode Gutter Indicators Doesn't Work on Some Repos

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-code, gutter

I have different repositories on my machine, lets named them X and Y. The gutter indicators works perfectly while I'm developing X. But in Y, it doesn't show the differences on the file.[image]

When I click the 'Source Control' panel in the VSCode and then select the file to show differences, it's showing the file like this:

[image]

It looks like there was a single line of code before the changes, but it's wrong. My git version is ***git version 2.29.2.windows.3*** and my VSCode version is ***1.55.2 (user setup)***. When I push my code for the Y, it shows the differences correctly on the GitHub. Any idea ? Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the issue. There is a Turkish character in my repository path. It causes a problem while fetching the differences.